# Passing data to Router Angular 2

Tags: angular

I need to pass data to my Router to use it in the destination component , i used `NavigationExtras` 's `QueryParam` but it shows parameters in the URL , is there an other way to pass data ?

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            queryParams: {
                "param1": true,
            }
        };
        this.router.navigate(['/page1/view'],navigationExtras);
```

Comment: do you want querystring like ?param=true or as /

Comment: neither, i need to pass data without showing it in the URL

Comment: can you pass it as @input? .. is it a compononet child?

Comment: nope that's the problem , it's another component
i need something similar to : ` {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  }`

Comment: so try to use a broadcasting maybe

Comment: how can i use it ?

Comment: try using set and get methods.

Comment: @Gautam where ?

Comment: before u route to ur new page set the data using set method and when you are on the routed page retrieve the set data using get method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, use a service.

I have a *simple* example here:

https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

```
import { Injectable } from ‘@angular/core’;
@Injectable() 
export class DataService { 
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

Or now in Angular v6 and higher:

```
import { Injectable } from ‘@angular/core’;
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
}) 
export class DataService { 
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try with something like this:

1 - Declare a Service like:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  // Observable sources (change activity)
    private emitChangeActivitySource = new Subject<any>();
    // Observable streams (change activity)
    changeActivityEmitted$ = this.emitChangeActivitySource.asObservable();
    // Service (change activity)
    emitChangeActivity(change: any) {
        this.emitChangeActivitySource.next(change);
    }

}
```

2- then when you want to get (subscribe ) for it:

```
import {  SharedService } from '../shared/services/index';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './full-layout.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./full-layout.component.scss']
})
export class FullLayoutComponent {


    constructor(private toasterService: ToasterService,
        private currentUserService: CurrentUserService,
        private menuService: MenuService,
        private router: Router,
        private auth: AuthService,
        private _sharedService: SharedService,
        private _activitiesService: ActivitiesService,
        private _router: Router) {


   _sharedService.changeActivityEmitted$.subscribe(
            activity => {
                this.data = activity;

                }
            });

            }

            }
```

3- where you want to trigger it:

```
this._sharedService.emitChangeActivitySource({name:'',descr:''});
```

Comment: in the third step i think u mean `this._sharedService.emitChangeActivity({name:'',descr:''});` , i changed it and i tested , i get this error cannot get 'outlet' of null

Comment: i think that there no relation between the two component to emit the event.. can u please explain to me what you do exactly in ur code ?

Comment: it was my fault , i fixed the outlet error.. , but when i subscribe in changeActivityEmitted$  there is no result, i think because we use the service in different components the source is empty when i inject it..

Comment: no it is made to share stuff in different component it's like Angularjs $broadcast() and $on()

Answer (score 0):

Before you navigate to your next page set the parameter using set method. then navigate to your next page

```
myFunction1(){
    this.uploadData = param;
    this.router.navigate(['/page1/view'])
}

set uploadData (param) {
        this._param = param;
}
```

once you are on the next page, retrieve the parameter using get method

```
myFunction2(){
        parameter = this.uploadData;
}   

get uploadData () {
            return this._param;
}
```

please note. this is just a sudo code. you will need to implement it as per your requirement.

you can more info about getters and setters from following links

[set method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

[get method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)